# Eclipse: Find All References In Project shortcut key not working

Tags: eclipse

Using Eclipse (believe I'm using Ganymede), I'd like F9 to "Find All References In Project".

I set up the key binding - it doesn't say there are any conflicts, "Binding" says F9 and "When" is set to Editing Java Source.

But it isn't working. I've tried re-opening the .java file (editor) I'm working with, and restarting Eclipse... still no good.  Anyone know what could be going on?

The project IS a Java project, and the .java source file is in a source folder within the build path (not just in a folder). Find references using the right click context menu works fine (Search->References->Project).

[image: Eclipse dialog]

Comment: Did you try binding it to a different key to see if it would work?

Comment: Good idea, but I tried F2 (after unbinding a conflict) and it still does nothing. Ctrl+Shift+G, no good either.

Comment: Is Ctrl+Shift+G a default for a global workspace Find References? The Flash Builder plugin I have installed did add that shortcut to find references editing Flex Source files, maybe that's the cause. Still, I unbinded those, set up Ctrl+Shift+G as the global workspace Find References shortcut, and that's not working either. And that doesn't explain why F2 or F9 don't work... Also have a WindowBuilder plugin installed (which adds some new options under "When").